# Avoid double call GET Ajax load

Tags: django, ajax

Well, I'm trying to create a graphical interface for a database using django.
I have to say that I'm trying to learn so I don't have too much experience with Frameworks, just with pure code.

The doubt I have is:
-When trying to create a filter system with checkboxes I have used Ajax to be able to update the view without having to refresh. Like this:

```
   $(document).on('click','#console_check_filter',function(){
        var ps_id;
        ps_id = $(this).attr("data-posts-id");
        $.ajax({
              url: "{% url 'list-view' %}",
              method: 'POST',
              data: {
                  'getfilter': ps_id,
                  'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
              },
              success: function (res, status,data) {
                 $("#list").load("/game/list-view");

              },
              error: function (res,ras,rus) {
              }
          });
      });
```

But I had the error that for every call I made with POST the AJAX function ().load() made another call which eliminated the variable that gave me the POST. This made it impossible for me to use the information received from the POST to create the filter.
Result: I click on the checkbox and in the console I get a call with the filtered list and then another one without filter, and as it is not only the last one that is rendered, which has no data.
To solve this I have used a globar variable to save the value in the POST and the ().load() return to make the GET call using the value saved in the GLOBAL.

```
filet=""
def game_list(request):
    global filet
    context = {}
    game_filter = request.GET.get('console_check_filter')
    games = Game.objects.all()

    game_post = games
    data = {'success': False}
    page = request.GET.get('page',1)
    game_console_filter=""
    context['games'] = games

    #if request.method=='POST':
    game_console_filter = request.POST.get('getfilter')
    if not game_console_filter:
        game_console_filter = request.GET.get('getfilter')


    if request.method=="POST":
        filet = get_game_console_filter(request,game_console_filter)
    context['games'] = games
    context['game_post'] = filet


    return render(request,'Jocs/list-view.html',context )
```

This doesn't seem elegant to me, I'm out of the woods, yes, but I don't think it's the best solution.

Any idea to avoid this happening to me?

A greeting and thank you very much for everything

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I am more stupid than I thought. In the end the solution was to send the variable by URL. Example:

AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click','#console_check_filter',function(){
   var ps_id;
   ps_id = $(this).attr("data-posts-id");
   $.ajax({
       url: "{% url 'list-view' %}",
       method: 'POST',
       data: {
             getfilter': ps_id,
             csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
              },
       success: function (res, status,data) {
                 $("#list").load("/game/list-view/?filters="+ps_id); > <-----HERE
              },
       error: function (res,ras,rus) {
              }
          });
      });
```

views.py:

```
#if request.method=='POST':
    game_console_filter = request.POST.get('getfilter')
    if not game_console_filter:
        game_console_filter = request.GET.get('filters') <---HERE
```

I think that if this is the right way to proceed, at least it's more elegant.

I hope someone else will find this answer useful.
Sorry for the inconvenience and for asking trivial questions. Greetings to all.